# How to make logwatch show a reboot event in the report?

Tags: logging, reporting, logwatch, reboot

Our environment consists of several workstations and servers, all RHEL (CentOS 7) and with logwatch (currently v7.4.0) installed. A custom cron job sends daily logwatch reports via email. The command used to generate the report is simply: `/usr/sbin/logwatch --format text` if it matters. All systems are regularly updated and rebooted by us admins but our users are also allowed to reboot their workstation manually. Of course there is `who -b` and `last -x` but we would like to add the reboot events to the daily logwatch report rather than adding a script which analyses the output of said commands.

How can logwatch be configured to detect a reboot (for whatever reason) and add the event to the generated report ?

Comment: I do not think `logwatch` can do this. What is the problem to create script?

Comment: Hey egeiter, @RomeoNinov  is indeed correct, and I'm furnishing a solution with the expectation that it will prove effective.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks, there is no problem. The idea is just to prevent additional emails and integrate the reboot information in the logwatch report email which we are already receiving.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting system reboots and adding them to Logwatch reports isn't something Logwatch is designed to do out of the box. However, you can create a custom Logwatch filter script to extract reboot events and include them in your daily report.
You'll need to create a custom filter script that can extract reboot events from system logs. You can write this script in Perl or another scripting language of your choice. The script should search for reboot-related entries in log files, such as /var/log/wtmp, /var/log/lastlog, or /var/log/messages.
Here's a simple Perl script that you can use as a starting point to detect system reboots in the /var/log/wtmp file and include the information in your Logwatch report. Please note that this script is a basic example and may require further customization to meet your specific needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $wtmp_file = "/var/log/wtmp";  # Adjust the path if necessary

# Get the current date
my $date = `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`;
chomp($date);

# Open the wtmp file for reading
open my $wtmp, $wtmp_file or die "Failed to open $wtmp_file: $!";

# Search for reboot events and collect relevant information
my @reboot_events;
my $reboot_event = 0;
while (my $line = <$wtmp>) {
    my ($user, $tty, $host, $boot_time) = unpack("A32A32A256I", $line);
    next unless defined $user and $user ne '';  # Skip empty entries

    if ($boot_time == 2) {
        # This is a reboot event
        push @reboot_events, "User: $user, TTY: $tty, Host: $host, Boot Time: " . scalar localtime($boot_time);
        $reboot_event = 1;
    }
}

close $wtmp;

# Generate Logwatch output
if ($reboot_event) {
    print "Reboot Events (from $wtmp_file):\n";
    print join("\n", @reboot_events) . "\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Please customize the `$wtmp_file` variable if your wtmp file is located in a different path. You can also modify the script to search other log files if you have additional logs that record reboot events.

Save this script to a file (e.g., /usr/local/bin/custom_reboot_report.pl), make it executable (chmod +x /usr/local/bin/custom_reboot_report.pl), and then include it in your Logwatch configuration, as described in the previous response.

Please note that this is a basic script, and you may need to adapt it to your specific environment and log file formats. Additionally, you should test the script thoroughly before deploying it to your production environment to ensure it works as expected.

Comment: Hi @R1w thank you for this excellent explanation with code example included. Unfortunately I am not able to see the previous response you referenced but I think I will be able to figure out how to integrate the custom script in the logwatch routine. I will try out your suggestion and report back.

Comment: @egeiter thank you for the kind words :-), i hope the solution works for you.